# Остановка и запуск потоков С++

Tags: c++, многопоточность

У меня есть несколько void которые одновременно работают после такой записи:

```
void example1(){}
void example2(){}
void start_threads(){

thread t1(example1);
thread t2(example2);

t1.join();
t2.join();
}

int main(){
    start_threads();
}
```

Но дальше я останавливаю эти два void через return();
*Выполняю какой то другой void...
И теперь мне нужно снова запустить эти потоки.
Способ снова вызвать функцию start_threads() не работает.
Как мне это сделать? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: А почему вы думаете что сможете вызвать её второй раз. Вы же отказались от главного потока, сделав Join. По идее - уберите два join и всё будет работать. (при условии что return из main не сделан)

Comment: Не работает(. Выдаёт диалоговое окно с ошибкой abort has been called. Но это уже хоть что то).

Comment: При условии что выход из main не сделан. Нужно ещё дописывать поведение. Выход из main и даёт abort.

Comment: Я что то слишком сильно затупил... Я могу сделать то что мне нужно и без остановки и запуска этих потоков. Извните за беспокойство. Но если вы не заняты пожалуйста опишите ваш последний комментарий, а то я совсем в нём ничего не понял.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, я чего-то не понимаю...

```
void example1(){ for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { cout << 1; this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);} }
void example2(){ for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { cout << 2; this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);} }
void start_threads()
{

    thread t1(example1);
    thread t2(example2);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    cout << endl;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    start_threads();
    cout << "Once more...\n";
    start_threads();
}
```

[Это](https://ideone.com/Mtv4Cz) не то, что вам нужно? Потоки запущены 2 раза...

Comment: Да, это то. Я уже так пробовал, но у меня зависал экран. И это похоже не из за потоков, это я где то что то не так написал...